# How do I make the correct call from services using Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, service, components

Below, I have created a service of name `util.service` to call in `manage-actives-crud.component.ts` inside `ngOnInit`
.
Saying that everything that is different from the modes 'create', 'edit' and 'view' should redirect the user to home. This solved the problem for when the user tries to write anything at the end of the url. But when I go to click the create button my page is also being redirected to home. Can someone please help me to identify what was declared wrong on line 25?

[image: invalidUr]

**Button "new" with bug**
[image: Button "new" with bug]

**file util.service.ts**

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
        
        @Injectable({
            providedIn: 'root'
        })
        
        export class UtilService
        {
            public mode: string;
        
            constructor(
                private router: Router
             ) { }
        
            public invalidUrl(url: any): void
            {
                if (this.mode !== 'create' && this.mode !== 'edit' && this.mode !== 'view') {
                void this.router.navigate(['home' + url])
                }    
            }
        }
```

**file manage-actives-crud.component.ts**

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { UtilService } from 'src/app/shared/services/util/util.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-packages-manage-actives-crud',
    templateUrl: './manage-actives-crud.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./manage-actives-crud.component.scss']
})
export class managePackagesCrudComponent implements OnInit {

    public loading: boolean;
    public mode: string = 'create';
    public id: string;

    constructor(
        private readonly route: ActivatedRoute,
        private readonly router: Router,
        private readonly util: UtilService
    ) { }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.loading = true;
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {       
            this.mode = params['mode'];
            this.id = params['id'];
            this.util.invalidUrl(this.router.url);
        });
        this.initData();
    }
```

Comment: which one is line 25? Please share more code like html

Comment: `public mode: string;` is undefined, where did you set the value of `mode` for `UtilService`. Also inside your `if` statement seems wrong, shouldn't be `void` there

Comment: The "bug" happens when I put this.util.invalidUrl(this.router.url); in the manage-actives.crud.component.ts file (line 25 I meant), but it solves one and bugs the other. The html is all right. The problem is that I don't know how to call services. I'm new to the area guys, sorry. :( @robert

Comment: Could you show me some ideal example of how to proceed? I'm new to this area and I'm getting beaten up in this part :( @penleychan

Comment: The "mode" variable in your service is never update -always is equal to 'undefined'-. you forget pass to yuor function invalidUrl the "mode" variable, some like: `this.util.invalidUrl(this.router.url,this.mode)`?

Comment: Not works yet :'( show message error "Expected 1 arguments, but got 2." @Eliseo

Comment: @SergeyKrimon, you also should define your function as `invalidUrl(url: any,mode:any){..here use mode, NOT this.mode..}`:

Comment: Yes, but it still doesn't work :( @Eliseo